# Finding all solutions for congruences

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

Decide which of the following congruences are solvable, and if so, find all solutions:

a) $x^2 \equiv c  \bmod 363$, where $c= 1,5,31$

b) $x^2 \equiv 54 \bmod 125$

Now, I know how to find which of those are solveable, but I have no idea how to find the solutions.

(For example b) is solvable).

Any ideas?

Comment: At $x=1$, $c=1$ is trivial.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes, but for the nontrivial congruences?Is there any method generally to find it? Or a method for specific cases?

Comment: Note that $x^2\equiv0,1\pmod3$.  Thus, we can already see $c=5$.

Comment: this is the modular log and not trivial, but it can be done depending on how many calculations you can afford.

Comment: for $c=1$ i have found $$x=1,122,241,362$$

Comment: Yes, use the symmetry of $(+x)^2=(-x)^2$ to find solutions faster.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner How?

Comment: @ChakaChaka From my last hint, one only needs to check the first half of the values from $1$ to $363$.

Comment: @SimpleArt you can get something cheaper by using CRT, and when attacking mod $11^2$ first solving $\bmod 11$ to avoid a ton of cases.

Comment: @SimpleArt But it's still 181 numbers to check...

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Why $mod \ 11$?

Comment: well, $363=11^2 \times 3$, you only have to check $22$ cases.

Comment: $11^2\times3=363$.  Same idea as I used to show $c=5$ is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps these general ideas can help you:

Suppose that we want to solve $x^k \equiv c \bmod p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_n^{\alpha_n}$

It suffices to find the solutions $\bmod p^a$ for each prime power and then combine them using the chinese remainder theorem.

So how can we solve $x^k\equiv c \bmod p^a$?

One way is to do it inductively over $a$.

First find all the solutions to $x^k \equiv p^{a-1}$, so when we check for the solutions to $x^k\equiv p^{a-1}$ we only have to check congruences which also solved the previous equation.